# Cubic monogenic number fields that are non euclidean

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm looking for explicit examples of $\alpha$ such that $\mathfrak{O}_k = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ for some cubic monogenic number field $k$ and where $\mathfrak{O}_k$ is not Euclidean. As much as possible, I'm hoping to find the simplest examples as I'm going to operate on their integer ring (as in add, multiply, modulo operations). I'm actually looking for simple monogenic fields of degree $\geq$ 3 with non-Euclidean integer rings and chose the cubic fields since I think computations would be simpler here.

Comment: $\mathfrak O_k$ will be non-Euclidean as soon as $k$ has class number larger than one (and conjecturally, this is equivalent - it is believed any cubic field, or any number ring with infinitely many units, which is a PID is also Euclidean). You can try generating examples in Sage.

Comment: Thank you! Altho I haven't heard of Sage before. How do I use it to generate examples?

Comment: [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org) is your friend! There are a lot of examples [here](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/?hst=List&degree=3&class_number=2&search_type=List) (not all of these are monogenic - you have to check). For example, [this one](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/3.1.331.1), [this one](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/3.1.331.1) and [this one](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/3.1.491.1). Look for cubic extensions with non trivial class number and an integral basis of the form $1, a, a^2$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thank you very much for mentioning LMFDB! I haven't heard of it before. It's a gem!

Answer (score 1):

Every prime of $R=\Bbb{Z}[(15)^{1/3}]$ above $p\nmid 15$ is unramified and $(3,(15)^{1/3})^3=(3),(5,(15)^{1/3})^3=(5)$ whence every prime ideal is invertible and $R$ is the ring of integers of $\Bbb{Q}((15)^{1/3})$.

Its class number is not one because $I=(2,(15)^{1/3}-1)$ is not principal.

This follows from a numerical check: we have a unit $u = 1-30 (15)^{1/3}+12 (15)^{2/3}\in (0,1)$, if $I=(a)$ then replacing $a$ by $\pm au^n$ we can assume that $a\in (u,1)$ so that $2/a\in (2,2/u)$.

$a = c_0+c_1(15)^{1/3}+c_2(15)^{2/3}$, $\sigma(a)=c_0+e^{2i\pi/3}c_1(15)^{1/3}+e^{4i\pi/3}c_2(15)^{2/3}$, we have $N(a)=a \sigma(a)\overline{\sigma(a)}=2$ whence $a\in (u,1)$,$2/a\in (2,2/u)$ gives some bound $|a|, |\sigma(a)|,|\overline{\sigma(a)}|< \sqrt{2/u}$ from which we get some bounds for the integers $c_j$, so we can test them all.

I won't do the computation but it suffices to check that $\det(c_0+c_1\pmatrix{0&0&-15\\1&0&0\\0&1&0}+c_2\pmatrix{0&0&-15\\1&0&0\\0&1&0}^2)\ne  2$ for $|c_j|<100/\sqrt{u}$.

Comment: Ohh I see. Thank you for this! However, is it an integer ring of a monogenic number field?

Comment: @Butterfly ??? This is what I proved at the beginning. Monogenic means $O_K=\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

Comment: Sorry, sorry. Thank you for clarifying. I only have beginner understanding of these things yet and I haven't encountered ramification before. What I only know is not every $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is an integer ring of some monogenic field that's why I asked. I'll definitely try to teach myself these advanced concepts. Thank you very much!

Comment: For $p\nmid 15$ when $x^3-15\bmod p$ is separable, it factors in a product of distinct irreducibles $f_j(x)$, then $(p,f_j((15)^{1/3}))$ are distinct maximal ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[(15)^{1/3}]$ and their intersection is $\prod_j(p,f_j((15)^{1/3}))=(p)$. This proves that every maximal ideals above such $p$ are invertible. It remains to check $p=3,p=5$ to find that $\Bbb{Z}[(15)^{1/3}]$ is a Dedekind domain.

Comment: It always works like that: the unramified maximal ideals are invertible and it remains to check the finitely many ramified ones.